# Maximize expected pay off value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Assume you sell chocolate bars for a price x greater than 0 and less than 10. You adjust the price often as you make a sell. After a while you construct a model measuring the sucess rate of making a sell with a price $x$ using the function $f(x)$.

Assuming the model is correct, what is the best price to charge such that you maximize your expected pay off value.

I am a bit confused about what I should do here exactly. I mean I could compute the expected pay off as $\int_0^{10} xf(x)dx$, but this value does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Why should it depend on $x$?

Comment: Don't I have to find the best price, i.e. $x$ that will maximize the expected pay off? I would expect the answer to be something like: We should sell a bar for 4.5 to maximize expected pay off.

Comment: Yeah so 4.5 is your answer, that is, you would get something like $\int_0^{10} xf(x)dx = 4.5$. There's no dependence on $x$

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a value larger than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the probability that if the price is $x$, then the sell occurs.

Let $t$ be the base price. Then, $x-t$ is the payoff if the sell occurs, and $-t$ is the payoff if the sell doesn't occur.

Then, the expected payoff at price $x$ is :
$$  \begin{align} \text{payoff}(x) &=f(x)(x-t)+(1-f(x))(-t) \\
&= xf(x)-t
\end{align}$$

Thus, $$\text{best price }= \displaystyle \text{arg max}_{0 \leq x \leq 10} xf(x) $$

This also holds if we say that there is no loss if the sell doesn't occur.

Comment: Thank you! With this I finally get a feasible value!